# Alternate button colour on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have generated a list of buttons , and would like each one to independently change colour when click, so they go red/green alternately on each click.

```
<?php
$getInfo = getAllRows();

$button = '<button type="button" id ="toggle" ></button>';?>


</php>
<html>
<div class ="enableButtons">
//there are 5 values to iterate over
<?php foreach ($getInfo):
echo $button;
?>
<?php endforeach ?>

                 </div>
 </html>

<script>
$('#toggle').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('green');

});

</script>

.green
{
    background-color:green;
}
```

The problem Im having is that only the first button seems to be toggling colour , the others dont do anything when I click! Also Im unsure how to make it toggle from red/green alternately.

Any help would be great cheers!

Comment: for dynamic buttons in for loop you should use the class and call the click event with that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `id`. It seems all the button will have same `id` which is wrong markup.

Try by replacing `id` with a common class

```
$button = '<button type="button" class="someCommonCLass" ></button>'
```

In js

```
$('.someCommonCLass').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('green');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ta3pLnjs/1/). Like others have suggested, you want to output your buttons with a `class` instead of an `id`, to make your buttons easier to select with jQuery. Here's an example, with nice CSS. Your buttons should be formatted like this.

```
<button type="button" class="toggle"> label </button>
```

Here's a working SO Snippet.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('green');

});
```

```css
.toggle {
    background-color:#df0606;
    padding:7px;
    border:1px solid red;
    color:white;
    font-size:1.18em;
    box-shadow:2px 4px black;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-right:4px;
}
.toggle:hover {
    background-color:#cd0101;
    padding:7px;
    border:1px solid red;
    color:#ff2a31;
    font-size:1.18em;
    box-shadow:2px 4px #510809;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-right:4px;
}

.green {
    color:white;
    padding:7px;
    border:1px solid lime;
    background-color:green;
    font-size:1.18em;
    box-shadow:2px 4px black;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-right:4px;
}
.green:hover {
    color:lime;
    padding:7px;
    border:1px solid lime;
    background-color:#12de09;
    font-size:1.18em;
    box-shadow:2px 4px #044f12;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-right:4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<p>
These buttons generated with PHP:
</p>
<div class ="enableButtons">
    <button type="button" class="toggle">One</button>
    <button type="button" class="toggle">Two</button>
    <button type="button" class="toggle">Three</button>
</div>
<p>
Here's some text. Text text text.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are generating a list of buttons so you should use class instead of `id` 
Try this:

```
$button = '<button type="button" class ="toggle" ></button>'
<script>
 $('.toggle').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('green');
 });

</script>
```